# iOS, Unexpected results when trying to render "transform scaled" view using UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimageview, render

I am trying to render a view and it's contents after a transformation using UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext. Even though the view is scaled down, when I render it, the image size is correct, but the contents are rendered at their original size (in this case they are cropped as opposed to fit to the view as expected.

[image]

here is a simple sample project: http://owolf.net/uploads/StackOverflow/ParentChildTransformTester.zip

To explain further: I create a parent view and a child view, add the child as a subview. Then I transform scale the parent view, which resizes the child as well (just as I want). Then I create an image context at the current frame size of the parent view, and render. Code below.

```
//create views
UIView *parentView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[parentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
[self.view addSubview:parentView];

UIView *childView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 100)];
[childView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[parentView addSubview:childView];

//log parent view size : result is device screen size
NSLog(@"parentView.frame.size, BEFORE tran: %f x %f", parentView.frame.size.width, parentView.frame.size.height);

float scaleFactor = 0.2;
CGAffineTransform trans = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
parentView.transform = trans;

//log parent view size after transform :  result is device screen size * 0.2
NSLog(@"parentView.frame.size, AFTER tran: %f x %f", parentView.frame.size.width, parentView.frame.size.height);


//attemt to render and save scaled parent view.
CGSize renderSize = CGSizeMake(parentView.frame.size.width, parentView.frame.size.height);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(renderSize.width, renderSize.height));

[[parentView layer] renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImage *renderedImage;
renderedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(renderedImage, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply the transformation to the current transformation matrix before you render the layer:

```
...
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, [[parentView layer] affineTransform]);

[[parentView layer] renderInContext:ctx];
...
```

Comment: Thanks! Do I need to reset the current transformation matrix after rendering?

Comment: No, the easiest thing would be: `CGContextSaveGState`, `CGContextConcatCTM`, render, `CGContextRestoreGState`, then conitnue drawing without the transformation applied to the current CTM.

Answer (score 0):

This worked: modified according to Graver's answer above.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(parentView.frame.size);
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, [[parentView layer] affineTransform]);
[[parentView layer] renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
renderedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(renderedImage, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
```